# Webview app cannot save downloaded file in device file system

Tags: javascript

I am writing a WebView android application to download a file and save it into my mobile device. The file can be downloaded but cannot be saved into my device.  What is happening, and how do I fix it?

```
        function downloadContentVersion(nodeId, version) {
        var url = '';
        self.getDownloadUrl(nodeId, version ? version.version : null).then(function (response) {
            url = response.data.data.contentUrl;
           alert('hi 1');

            return $http({
                'method': 'GET',
                'responseType': 'arraybuffer',
                'url':  config.basePath + url.substring(url.indexOf('/downloadURL'))
            });
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
                window.open( config.basePath + url, '_blank');
                alert('hey' + window.open );
            } else {
                var blob = new Blob([response.data], {
                    type: response.headers("Content-Type")
                });
                saveAs(blob, version ? version.filename : extractFileName(response));
                alert('hello' + blob);
            }
        });
    }

    function extractFileName(response) {
        var url = response.config.url;
         alert('oook' + url );
        return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    }
```

Comment: What does the `saveAs` function do? What do you mean when you say "cannot be saved into my device"? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? At what point does it fail?

Comment: once i click the download button in my apps its content can be download but never save the content in folder. what should i do?

Comment: This is the function for extractFileName(response). function extractFileName(response) {
            var url = response.config.url;
            return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        }

Comment: you should edit the question to include sufficient details (including the missing `extractFileName` and `saveAs` functions). You also have not answered the questions I asked such as did you step through the code in a debugger

Comment: I did try debugging but there are no errors show. The content is downloaded successfully but only cannot save the content into the device. What is the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: nobody can possibly help you with the problem since you still haven't included sufficient details. The code you have in the question is incomplete as it is missing the `saveAs` function. I suggest you try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is a minimal example that people can actually try to run and see what your problem is. Without more detail your question will remain unanswered